# UIScrollview with multiple images and pinch to zoom

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I am trying to duplicate the Photos app on the iPhone.  Meaning, a scrollview with multiple images, and each image can be pinched to zoom in/out.

The Apple ScrollViewSuite example code only deals with 1 image inside of a scrollview.  I have found that with multiple images, scrolling through the images becomes unpredictable.  Also, the view becomes uncentered after pinching to zoom.

I have found this on Stack Overflow: [Zoom UIScrollView with multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380643/zoom-uiscrollview-with-multiple-images)

However, what am I supposed to write in the scrollview delegate functions?

Comment: How about Apple's [PhotoScroller](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=photoscroller%20apple%20sample&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fsamplecode%2FPhotoScroller%2FIntroduction%2FIntro.html&ei=B0OFT7CzEY_SrQeJ2rXSBg&usg=AFQjCNHK6ZW1WphEOlE6XEu7OhfRJ7Zi1g) Application?

Answer (score 6):

This is what I found to work. Supports multiple images with paging and zooming. Enjoy!

```
#define VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG (1)

@implementation SVViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    mainScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    mainScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    mainScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    CGRect innerScrollFrame = mainScrollView.bounds;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        UIImageView *imageForZooming = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:  
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page%d", i + 1]]];
        imageForZooming.tag = VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG;

        UIScrollView *pageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:innerScrollFrame];
        pageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
        pageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0f;
        pageScrollView.zoomScale = 1.0f;
        pageScrollView.contentSize = imageForZooming.bounds.size;
        pageScrollView.delegate = self;
        pageScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        pageScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [pageScrollView addSubview:imageForZooming];

        [mainScrollView addSubview:pageScrollView];

        if (i < 2) {
            innerScrollFrame.origin.x += innerScrollFrame.size.width;
        }
    }

    mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(innerScrollFrame.origin.x + 
    innerScrollFrame.size.width, mainScrollView.bounds.size.height);

    [self.view addSubview:mainScrollView];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [scrollView viewWithTag:VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
} 

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

@end
```