# UIScrollView Zoom on shake effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I am working on application in which i need to zoom the scroll view on shake effect so user will not touch the screen to pinch or double tap.

I have implemented the code by looking in to this tutorial:
[Zoom UIScrollView with multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380643/zoom-uiscrollview-with-multiple-images)

I got the call in a delegate:

```
viewForZoomingInScrollView
```

But the image view not zoom in or out. 
When i touch the screen after the delegate called the scroll view is zoom in. But content in scroll view not zoom in or out. It remains as it is.

Even some time i did not get call in the following delegate:

```
scrollViewDidZoom
scrollViewDidEndZooming
```

So do i need to call layout subview after viewForZoomingInScrollView if yes where?
From my understanding the view is not zooming because i have not pinch or double tap the scroll view. 
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Those you mentioned are UIScrollView delegate methods and they are called when the scrollView will\did actually zoom, not to perform the zooming. 
To perform the zoom programmatically you need to use `zoomToRect:animated:` and passing the portion of your scorllView's subview you want to scroll and wether it needs to be animated or not.

Hope it helps.